# Unit Test Missing Branch Coverage in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I have been trying to get my head around unit testing `equals` method in java to cover all branches. There is one branch missing. I tried to look up couple of [resources](https://www.guru99.com/junit-assert.html), but was not very helpful. Here is my code which I am trying to unit test it.

```
public boolean isValid(Item item) {

    return !StringUtils.isEmpty(item.getCat()) &&        //both branches covered
            !StringUtils.isEmpty(item.getDog()) &&   //both branches covered
            !StringUtils.isEmpty(item.getDogCat()) &&       //both branches covered
            (String.format("%s|%s", item.getDog(), item.getCat())  //here one branch missing
                    .equals(item.getDogCat());
}
```

Unit Test:

```
    boolean expectedValue = false;

    private static final Item ITEM_4 = 
      Item.builder()
            .dogCat("bow|meow")
            .dog("bow")
            .cat("meow")
            .build();


    @Test
    public void testIsValidWhenCatIsNull() {
        boolean actualValue = itemValidator.isValid(ITEM_1);
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsValidWhenDogIsNull() {
        boolean actualValue = itemValidator.isValid(ITEM_2);
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsValidWhenDogCatIsNull() {
        boolean actualValue = itemValidator.isValid(ITEM_3);
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIfDogCatMatchesConcatenatedDogCat() {
        itemValidator.isValid(ITEM_4);
        Assert.assertEquals(String.format("%s|%s" ,"bow", "meow"), ("bow|meow"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testIfDogCatDoesNotMatchesConcatenatedDogCat() {
        itemValidator.isValid(ITEM_4);
        Assert.assertNotEquals(String.format("%s|%s", "bow", "meow"), ("bow|whoop"));
}
```

Unit testing world is quite new to me, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please explain more? I am guessing it is about code coverage for that particular branch, if this is the case then you should probably pass the right data, and if you are passing right set of data then it seems that last condition will never execute as some other condition is always true for that given set of data.

Comment: @BilboBaggins the last condition just checks if concatenation of Dog and Cat is correct or not. For example, getDog() returns "bow" and getCat() returns "meow", and getDogCat() returns "bow|meow". Last condition verifies that concatenation is true or not.

Comment: @BilboBaggins can you please explain further about - "if you are passing right set of data then it seems that last condition will never execute as some other condition is always true" ?

Comment: @Techiee I think && short-circuits if any of the previous conditions become false. Then it won't need to evaluate the remaining conditions. Whereas if it was || operator you could have argued that if one of the conditions become true then don't need to evaluate the rest.

Comment: @YugSingh so you are trying to say that I should have a test case covering all the 3 && conditions?

Comment: "`Assert.assertEquals(String.format("%s|%s", "bow", "meow"), ("bow|meow"));`" why are you testing that `String.format` works?

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't intend to test `String.format`, I am just trying to test the last condition, please correct me if I am doing something wrong in the last two test cases.

Comment: @AndyTurner And why is he calling the isValid() method without using its result ...

Comment: @Techiee We do not know what you ITEM_* objects look like. Tip: this should be visible in the test method itself (create the data there!) or else you risk losing control over your test cases!

Comment: @Amadán: added the object ITEM_4, similarly, I have ITEM_1, ITEM_2 and so on.

Comment: @AndyTurner any idea how should test the last condition?

Comment: @Techiee Have you tried an item with a dogCat not matching the dog and cat, like: Item.builder().dogCat("lizzy").dog("whiskey").cat("jar")?

Comment: @AndyTurner Good catch, I missed that one for String.format. I agree with Andy that you don't even need to test it. By right data, I meant to say, this that you are testing isEmpty in your conditions are you passing everything that is not empty?

Comment: If you are using Apache Commons Lang then it also has a method call isNotEmpty :)

Comment: @Amadán: thats awesome. That helped! Thank you so much. `Item.builder().dogCat("lizzy").dog("whiskey").cat("jar")`

Comment: I should have created an object with incorrect concatenation and should have tested with that object. Understood my mistake. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Techiee Here you simply missed an error class: you only tested with valid data but not with invalid data. Generally spoken testing with correct data is easy but doesn't give you too much information about your sut's (system under test) correctness. You always want to test the edge case. Try to "break" your sut and verify a defined behaviour for those cases.  Usually the defined behaviour would be throwing a dedicated exception.

Comment: @Amadán something like `@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)` ?

Comment: Yeah, or Assert.assertThrows(ExpectedException.class, () -> { ... }) with JUnit 5, Assertions.assertThatThrownBy(() -> { ... }).isInstanceOf(ExpectedException.class) with AssertJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Amadan for pointing out the correct answer. I am just framing the response here so that it can be useful for others. To cover both the branches for equals method, we need to provide two different input objects, one for the equals and other that is not equal. For example, the input objects should look like this:

```
private static final Item ITEM_4 = 
  Item.builder()
        .dogCat("bow|meow")
        .dog("bow")
        .cat("meow")
        .build();

private static final Item ITEM_5 = 
  Item.builder()
        .dogCat("bow|meow")
        .dog("bow")
        .cat("whoop")
        .build();

    @Test
    public void testIfDogCatMatchesConcatenatedDogCat() {
        boolean actualValue = itemValidator.isValid(ITEM_4);
        Assert.assertTrue(actualValue);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIfDogCatDoesNotMatchesConcatenatedDogCat() {
        boolean actualValue = itemValidator.isValid(ITEM_5);
        Assert.assertFalse(actualValue);
    }
```

This way both the branches can be covered for unit testing.